# GWT Image setUrl()

Tags: java, gwt

i am using - and new to - **GWT** and i made an **`Image`** Widget to view an image. This image is found on my file system i wrote.

```
String src = "file:///D:/myfolder/myfile.jpg";
Image image = new Image();
image.setUrl(src);
```

but image doesn't appear!

Comment: How are you serving the file?

Comment: Ummm... you should accept some of the answers you have received in previous questions.

Comment: what do you mean of serving?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify either the whole URL (`http://www.example.com/img/myfile.jpg`) or (better yet) just relative to the root: `/img/myfile.jpg`. And, of course, you have to place your images in your [WAR](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions) directory.

That's the simple setup. If you have more images and want to optimize fetching them (many images -> many requests to the server), have a look at the [ClientBundle](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ImageResource).